# Python: Creating a leaderboard and saving data

Tags: python, json, pyqt

I have almost finished Quiz application in GUI and i'm trying to make a leaderboard so it will show all the names in Label.

But how can this be possible? do i need to create a text file, from where i can import the names? if so:

- How can i parse text into files using Python? (For this instance from QLineEdit)
- How can i import its data? (In bash scripting something equivalent to grep)

---

Should i make another python file and add array variables into them?

How can i append data to arrays other file?

```
import leaderboards #Import leaderboards.py

in leaderboards board.append("name1") #Should it be something like this?
```

---

Otherwise how can i do this with Json or some other database scripts?
(without accessing http protocol, game to be offline)

- What do i need to do to make leaderboard data file in Json? (can i do it with simple arrays)
- How can i parse data to Json file?
- How can i import Json file to Python and print it?

Would be very thankful for explanation, for instance Json file name is Data.json.

Can i incude compile Json files in PyQt resources file?

---

Also if i compile Python to Executable, how can i include this data files?

Sorry for making it too general, i couldn't find specific questions regarding to mine.

Comment: use a json file, it would behave as a mini DB:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

every time you will load the file and update it - just like a db

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try it! @OhadtheLad but i need more information about creating leaderboard there, i have barely worked with json files.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html).

Answer (score 1):

2 methods below, reads and writes to json file.
The file structure is similar to a dict.

```
import json

def json_load_file(json_file):
    with open(json_file) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        return json_data

def json_dump_to_file(json_file, json_dict):
    with open(json_file, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_dict, outfile, indent=4)
```

After that when a game is ended update the dict, and save it, just an example:

```
def update_board(json_file, latest_game_score):
    leaderboard_dict = json_load_file(json_file)
    do_stuff-> update the dict if required (example curr_score> score in file)
    when board is updated call->
    json_dump_to_file("/root/board.json",leaderboard_dict)
```

Comment: My apologies for being too annoying, but i don't quite understand the syntax of json files. where should i put the original name of file in first code?

Comment: https://github.com/ShellRox/Questions-and-Problems/blob/master/Syntax.py should it be something like this?